# Show table headers in a row

Tags: html, datatable, repeat

I have below table where the headers and data are showing perfectly but in a same column. Instead I need to show them in a proper table format. Unfortunately, I am unable to do so.

Can someone please help me?

Please find the image how it looks like now.
[image: Validation Rule Table needs to look like Field Names table]

This is my code for Field Names table which is fine.

```
<div style = "margin:0px 200px 0px 50px;">

                              <apex:dataTable style="background-color: #9e9494;" id="Randomtext" value="{!fieldMap[key1]}" var="listElementelements2" border="1">
                                 <apex:column width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff;"   headerClass="headerStyle"  headerValue="Field Name" value="{!listElementelements2.Name}"/>
                                 <apex:column width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff;"   headerClass="headerStyle"  headerValue="Field Type" value="{!listElementelements2.Field_Type__c}"/>
                                 <apex:column width="500" style="background-color: #ffffff;"  headerClass="headerStyle" headerValue="Object Name" value="{!listElementelements2.Object_Name__c}"/>
                                 <apex:column width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff;"  headerClass="headerStyle"  headerValue="Dependency Name" value="{!listElementelements2.Dependency__c }"/>
                                 <apex:column width="100" style="background-color: #ffffff;"  headerClass="headerStyle"  headerValue="Picklist Values" value="{!listElementelements2.Picklist_Values__c}"/>

                              </apex:dataTable>
                           </div>
```

**HTML Code for Validation Rule table**

```
<table id="contacttable">
                           <tr> 
                            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Configuration__c.Fieldsets.Validation_Rule}" var="varFieldName"> 

                              <div id="Randomtext">

                                <th style="background-color: #9e9494;border-width: thick thick;">{!varFieldName.Label}</th>

                              </div>

                              <div>
                                <apex:repeat value="{!configMap[key1][key2]}" var="listElement">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!listElement}" var="listElementelements"  >

                                    <tr>  
                                       <td style="background-color: #ffffff;border-width: thick thick;">{!listElementelements[varFieldName]}</td>   
                                     </tr> 
                                </apex:repeat>
                              </apex:repeat>
                              </div>

                            </apex:repeat>
                           </tr>
                          </table>
```

After Tushar's solution it managed to be in a row but second set of data gets into same problem.

Scrrenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that you want to put a table into a table cell of another table?

Comment: I just want to create a table as in picture. The dataset needs to fit in vertically.

Comment: Hi @KeithC. Can you please help me here?                                                                                   https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223590/word-visualforce-page-width-narrower-than-table-width-required             I have tried using overflow-wrap as said here but I am not getting my desired output. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/

Comment: Please don't add comments directed at an individual that are just saying "please help"; it is really up to contributors to choose to help. Sounds like you should post another question (linked back to this one) detailing the new problem. Or un-accept the answer if that did not solve the original problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the table Header in a row. You need just this. You just need to use Tr, th tag to make it work.

```
<tr> 
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Configuration__c.Fieldsets.Validation_Rule}" var="varFieldName"> 
    <th style="background-color: #9e9494;border-width: thick thick;">{!varFieldName.Label}</th>
</apex:repeat>
</tr>
```

As I am not aware how you are filling the data but I think you need to change your code to make it work.

```
<table id="contacttable">
    <tr> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Configuration__c.Fieldsets.Validation_Rule}" var="varFieldName"> 
        <th style="background-color: #9e9494;border-width: thick thick;">{!varFieldName.Label}</th>
    </apex:repeat>
    </tr>


    <apex:repeat value="{!configMap[key1][key2]}" var="listElement">
        <apex:repeat value="{!listElement}" var="listElementelements"  >
    <tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Configuration__c.Fieldsets.Validation_Rule}" var="varFieldName">
                <td style="background-color: #ffffff;border-width: thick thick;">{!listElementelements[varFieldName]}</td>   
            </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>

</table>
```

I have changed the position of fieldset repeat to make it works.

Comment: Thanks Tushar! But now though the row is fine the second set of data gets into same kind of problem. I have attached the image in question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: @user3919803 Changed the position of tr. Check now.

Comment: @TusharSharma  Just one small issue I find the table data in a row not showing in full content as it exceeds page size in width. I find like shrinking the table data to fit in one page should be fine with width:100% in style but seems this not working in my case. Can you please suggest any way out?

Comment: @Testing_SFDC I suggest you post a new question with code and UI screenshots. To get the better answer.

Comment: Hi Tushar please find separately asked the question here.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223590/word-visualforce-page-width-narrower-than-table-width-required